# Output overwriting previously saved variables in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

This maybe of benefit to anybody trying to dynamically populate an ArrayList.

`Spikes[]` is an array representing a gameboard.

Beneath is a conditional statement.

```
if(Spikes[inte1]>=1 && Spikes[inte2]>=1 && Spikes[destination1]>=0 && Spikes[destination2]>=0){
```

inte1 and inte2 are int's representing initial location of a piece.
destination1 and destination2 are ints representing initial location + dice roll;

As Spikes is a gameboard, the condition can be met by many initial locations + dices rolls so many different destinations.

Many possible moves can be generated if condition is met.

My problem is that (if the condition is met) when i save the possible moves to an ArrayList, the 4 integers generated by the first 'possible move' are overwritten by the next 4 possible move integers which are overwritten by subsequent.

Thus, i am not saving all possible moves to any arraylist available for sorting later.

I have tried 
saving each variable separately into int arrays to be amalgamated later but still overwrites.
Tried creating an gameboard object but got error.

Output can be a 1D or 2D arraylist.

```
if(Spikes[0]>=1 && Spikes[inte2]>=1 && Spikes[destination1]>=0 &&      
Spikes[destination2]>=0){
c.addMoveToArray(inte1, inte2, destination1, destination2);}

public int addMoveToArray (int inte1, int inte2, int destination1, int 
destination2) {

ArrayList<Integer> plist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
plist.add(inte1); plist.add(inte2); plist.add(destination1);        
plist.add(destination2); 
for (int i=0; i<plist.size();i++) {
System.out.println(plist);
}

Output in console

[5, 0, 8, 10]
[6, 0, 9, 11]
[7, 0, 10, 12]
[8, 0, 11, 13]
```

Comment: Did you use indexing or `.add()`, if you used the first, the previous will be overwritten

Comment: Add some more code and exact error/exception

Comment: You are creating a new ArrayList every time you call addMoveToArray, then throw that list away after you print its contents

Comment: Fishy. If we’re to say something qualified, please take the time to produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your `for` loop prints the *entire* `plist` for each element in it, that is four times. I seriously doubt that the output you show us comes from the code you show us.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating a Move class, where each instance contains the two "from" indices and the two "to" indices, then add instances of Move to the ArrayList. Then when you do make a move, clear the array list so you can start again with a new set of possible moves.